# Heavy Cube Word Problem

Tags: word-problem

There are eight cubes. One of them is heavier than the others, and we need to find it (They are all identical). How can we tell, using a balance, which cube is the heavy one in two weighings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide them into three groups: two groups of three and one group of two. Now weigh the two groups of three against each other. If one is heavier, you narrowed it down to three. If they are equal you narrowed it down to two.

Can you see how you can now complete the task, with just one more weighing?

Comment: Yes, I had done this before. But my issue was I could not solve this in two weighings.

Comment: Is it possible to do this only with two weighings?

Comment: @Dan He did tell you how to do it in $2$ weighings, I assume you didn't get the explanation. You have groups of: $[3][3][2]$. First you weight $[3]$ and $[3]$, if it is equal, then you weight two from the group of $[2]$ and you find the heavier one. If the $[3]$ and $[3]$ have a heavier side, you weight the $3$ from the heavier side by putting one aside and weighting two singles. Now if it is equal, the one laying aside is the heavier. If the weighting has a heavier side, it is the heavier one. Done in just $2$. Got it?

Comment: @Matta Ah, yes I see. So it is conditional. Thank you for pointing that out!